# How can I rotate annotated seaborn heatmap data and legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, heatmap

I created to a seaborn heatmap to summarize Teils_U coefficients. The data is horizontally displayed in the heatmap. Now, I would like to rotate the data and the legend. I know that you can roate the x axis and y axis labels in a plot, but how can I rotate the data and the legend ?

This is my code:

```
#creates padnas dataframe to hold the values
theilu = pd.DataFrame(index=['Y'],columns=matrix.columns)
#store column names in variable columns
columns = matrix.columns

#iterate through each variable
for j in range(0,len(columns)):
    #call teil_u function on "ziped" independant and dependant variable -> respectivley x & y in the functions section
    u = theil_u(matrix['Y'].tolist(),matrix[columns[j]].tolist())
    #select respecive columns needed for output
    theilu.loc[:,columns[j]] = u
    #handle nans if any  
    theilu.fillna(value=np.nan,inplace=True)

 #plot correlation between fraud reported (y) and all other variables (x)
 plt.figure(figsize=(20,1))
 sns.heatmap(theilu,annot=True,fmt='.2f')
 plt.show()
```

Here an image of what I am looking for:

[image]

Please let me know if you need and sample data or the teil_u function to recreate the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The parameters of the annotation can be changed via `annot_kws`. One of them is the rotation.

Some parameters of the colorbar can be changed via `cbar_kwsdict`, but the unfortunately the orientation of the labels isn't one of them. Therefore, you need a handle to the colorbar's ax. One way is to create an ax beforehand, and pass it to `sns.heatmap(..., cbar_ax=ax)`. An easier way is to get the handle afterwards: `cbar = heatmap.collections[0].colorbar`.

With this `ax` handle, you can change more properties of the colorbar, such as the orientation of its labels. Also, their vertical alignment can be changed to get them centered.

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.rand(1, 12)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,2))
heatmap = sns.heatmap(data, cbar=True, ax=ax,
                      annot=True, fmt='.2f', annot_kws={'rotation': 90})
cbar = heatmap.collections[0].colorbar
# heatmap.set_yticklabels(heatmap.get_yticklabels(), rotation=90)
heatmap.set_xticklabels(heatmap.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(cbar.ax.get_yticklabels(), rotation=90, va='center')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thank you for your answers, that was very helpful !

Answer (score 3):

You can pass argument to `ax.text()` (which is used to write the annotation) using [the `annot_kws=` argument](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html?highlight=heatmap#seaborn.heatmap).

Therefore:

```
flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
ax = sns.heatmap(flights, annot=True, fmt='d', annot_kws={'rotation':90})
```

[image]